# Chains of people names

Tags: combinatorics

> Consider the set $X$ of possible names for people. Let $(x, y) \in P$
>   (in the partial order) if and only if $x$ ends in a consonant and $y$
>   ends in a vowel. What is the length of the longest chain here? Give a
>   total order of the elements in $X$.

I don't really get how it is a binary relation and how to approach this problem.

Comment: constant --> consonant?

Comment: What is a possible name? Was there any information given about this?

Comment: There wasn't any.

Comment: How is the letter $y$ (and, dare I ask, $w$) handled?

Comment: @Sloan:  I don't think it matters as long as you define the end of each name unambiguously as a vowel or consonant.  You then have a partition of the elements of $X$ into two disjoint sets and elements of $P$ have to have the first element come from a specific one an the second element come from the other.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are to consider the names in $X$ to be single words, not a first name/last name pair.  Hint:  if a name ends in a consonant it can only be the first element of a pair, while if it ends in a vowel it can only be the second element of a pair.  How long a chain can you make?  I think the last sentence is a completely separate question-you are just asked to define a new relation that is a total order.